# Array function not iterating using array_shift()

Tags: php, arrays, arrow-functions

Below, the arrow function when called, why am I only getting the first entry?

```
<?php

$stack = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");
$fruit = fn() => array_shift($stack);

var_dump($fruit());
var_dump($fruit());
var_dump($fruit());
var_dump($fruit());
```

Gives:

```
string(6) "orange"
string(6) "orange"
string(6) "orange"
string(6) "orange"
```

https://3v4l.org/6sTm9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php):

> A by-value binding means that it is not possible to modify any values from the outer scope

and:

> Arrow functions capture variables by value automatically ... When a variable used in the expression is defined in the parent scope it will be implicitly captured by-value

Thus your function cannot modify the value of `$stack`, and so it returns the same value each time. To do what you want (without a parameter to the function) you need an anonymous function:

```
$fruit = function () use (&$stack) { return array_shift($stack); };

var_dump($fruit());
var_dump($fruit());
var_dump($fruit());
var_dump($fruit());
```

Output:

```
string(6) "orange"
string(6) "banana"
string(5) "apple"
string(9) "raspberry"
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/54WOJ)

You can use an arrow function if you're willing to pass a parameter:

```
$stack = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");
$fruit = fn(&$s) => array_shift($s);

var_dump($fruit($stack));
var_dump($fruit($stack));
var_dump($fruit($stack));
var_dump($fruit($stack));
```

Output:

```
string(6) "orange"
string(6) "banana"
string(5) "apple"
string(9) "raspberry"
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/XElrH)

Comment: I also think this part from the manual is useful: _"Arrow functions capture variables by value automatically ... When a variable used in the expression is defined in the parent scope it will be implicitly captured by-value"_

Comment: @NickParsons good point; I've included that in the answer.